# Не могу найти минимальный элемент в коллекции

Tags: java, list, коллекции, arraylist

Ребят, почему ошибка? Что ему не нравится?

```
import org.belsut.estryn.lessons.task02.details.Detail;

import java.util.*;

public class Sorter {
    private List<Detail> details = new ArrayList<>();

    public Sorter(List<Detail> details) {
        this.details = details;
    }

    private int getMinTime() {
        int min = Collections.min(details);
        return min;
    }
}
```

Возникает ошибка компиляции:

> `min(java.util.Collection<? extends T>)` in `Collections` cannot be applied to (`java.util.List<import org.belsut.estryn.lessons.task02.details.Detail>`)
>
> reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exists to that Detail conform to Comparable

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Collections.min`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min(java.util.Collection)) принимает коллекцию объектов, которые реализуют `Comparable`:

```
<T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T min(Collection<? extends T> coll)
```

Ошибка говорит о том, что класс `Detail` не реализует интерфейс `Comparable<Detail>` и, соответственно, метод не знает как сравнивать объекты и определять минимум.

Об этом написано в сообщении об ошибке:

> reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) `T` exists to that `Detail` conform to `Comparable<? super T>`

Кроме того, нужно заметить, что `min` вернет Вам объект типа `Detail`, а не `int` который Вы ожидаете получить.

Пути решения проблемы:

- Реализовать `Comparable<Detail>` в классе `Detail`.
- Воспользоваться перегрузкой [`min`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min(java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Comparator)), которая принимает компаратор. Так Вы сможете сортировать по заданному полю, например.
- Воспользоваться Stream API: использовать [`Stream.min`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#min-java.util.Comparator-) или сначала [`Stream.mapToInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) затем [`IntStream.min`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#min--). Посмотрите пример №3 здесь: [Finding Max/Min of a List or Collection](https://www.baeldung.com/java-collection-min-max).

P.S. Сообщение об ошибке мне пришлось перепечатать. Эти полминуты жизни мне никто не вернет. Поэтому сообщения об ошибке нужно целиком копировать и вставлять в вопрос с виде текста.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Прошу прощения, я учту Ваши замечания

Comment: @ВладиславЭстрин Пожалуйста. Всего доброго!

Comment: Отлично разжевали :), особенно PS